# Nuxtjs - Axios API calls in asyncData after the first SSR load fail on Safari

Tags: safari, nuxt.js

All API calls made using nuxt-axios-module @nuxtjs/axios fail / give error only on Safari browser when you navigate through page with client side loading (SSR first time load works fine).

The error given in Safari console is vague and not much to be extracted from it.
Has anyone have this issue before? It is consistent for all different API calls and they all follow the same pattern: Using $axios in asyncData and fail after the first SSR load.

Error:

[image]

All other browsers work, including IE11 even.

I've tried Nuxt's modern mode on both 'client' and 'server' modes, to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was unrelated to nuxt. It was my nginx server sending the following alongside OPTIONS requests and Safari apparently cannot handle that.

```
add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
```

Comment: As I have the same problem I wonder what you did to fix the problem? Can you post your nginx configuration steps which helped to resolve the problem?